# Reading ~/.aws/credentials from Spring Boot Spring Cloud

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am new to AWS and Spring Cloud.  I have accomplished a simple AWS Java Application where the AWS credentials are stored in ~/.aws/credentials file.  It works just fine.  I moved to a new project in Spring Boot and Spring Cloud.  I would like to continue using the ~/.aws/credential that I have set up for the Java application.  However, I have not been able to find a way to load the credentials from the credentials file. I had to move the access key and secret key to the aws-config.xml.

```
    <aws-context:context-credentials>
       <aws-context:simple-credentials access-key="${accessKey:}" secret-key="${secretKey:}"/>
    <aws-context:context-resource-loader/>
```

When I accomplished this, the Spring Boot and Spring Cloud application worked fine. However, keeping the information in the xml file is not the safest way because I am using GitHub.

Can someone point me in the direction whereby I can pull the information from the ~/.aws/credentials file into Spring Boot /Spring Cloud using Maven?

Thank you for taking the time reading my post.

Russ

Comment: Are you running the app itself in AWS (EC2 instance) or is the app running outside AWS with access to AWS resources?

Answer (score 1):

try below settings

```
cloud:
  aws:
    credentials:
      instanceProfile: false
      useDefaultAwsCredentialsChain: false
      profileName: <name>
      profilePath: ${user.home}/.aws/credentials
```

Answer (score 0):

[Instance Profile](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_instance_profile_configuration) sounds like the right option!

It's a IAM-role that lives on instances, without the need to hardcode credentials in code.

Spring Cloud's [Maven setup guide](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_spring_boot_auto_configuration) :)